# is there any IE javascript debugger?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, firebug

I am looking for a good IE javascript debugger, i have used firebug lite but it seems not so explicit like the real firebug about js errors.
How to know the js errors in internet explorer with exact line number and js file name?
please help.

Comment: Have you tried hitting F12 in IE and using the dev console?

Comment: Yes. IE8 and above has one built in. Just press F12.

Comment: yes bit slow but it works, I could fix an IE issue with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is.  If you hit F-12 in later versions of IE, you'll get IE's dev tools. They're nowhere near as good as what's in Chrome or FF, but you can check ajax requests, inspect the dom, inspect and set breakpoints in JavaScript code, and even emulate previous versions of IE.

[image]